# Can I pass the this._id value from one template helper to another with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the following templates (.html) with their respected managers (.js files):

- adminManageCategories
- adminAddCategory
- adminUpdateCategory

Consider the following:

```
<template name="adminManageCategories">
    {{#each category}}
        <div class="clickme">{{title}}</div>
    {{/each}}
 
    {{> adminUpdateCategory}}
</template>
```

Notice the {{> adminUpdateCategory}} is outside of the iteration. This is also a form, and I want to keep it on the same page.

And admin_manage_categories.js

```
Template.adminManageCategories.events({
    "click .clickme": function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this._id);
    }
});
```

Notice the console.log() function, which works, as the template manager is smart enough to know the ID of the item that was clicked.

What I want to do is load this items values into the form when clicked. My example above is slim, but in my real data I have a title, sort order, among other things.

So my question is, what is the proper way to pass the _id from the adminManageCategories template to the adminUpdateCategory template, which is the form?

I can hack at this with JavaScript and make things happen, but I think I'm missing a "Meteor way" of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`ReactiveVar`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) to store the currently clicked item.

First you need to run `meteor add reactive-var`, as it's not a package added by default in a standard meteor web app.

**JS**:

```js
Template.adminManageCategories.created=function(){
  // instantiate the reactive-var in the created callback
  // we store it as a property of the template instance
  this.currentItemId=new ReactiveVar(null);
};

Template.adminManageCategories.helpers({
  // this helper reactively returns the currently clicked item
  currentItem:function(){
    // retrieve the reactive-var from the template instance...
    var currentItemId=Template.instance().currentItemId.get();
    // ...to fetch the correct collection document
    return Items.findOne(currentItemId);
  }
});

Template.adminManageCategories.events({
  "click .clickme": function(event,template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // assign the correct item id to the reactive-var attached to this template instance
    template.currentItemId.set(this._id);
  }
});
```

**HTML**:

```html
<template name="adminManageCategories">
  {{#each category}}
    <div class="clickme">{{title}}</div>
  {{/each}}
  <p>Current item title is : {{currentItem.title}}</p>
  {{! pass the currentItem as a parameter to your child template this will be
      accessible as {{item}} in the HTML and "this.item" in JS helpers or
      "this.data.item" in created/rendered/destroyed callbacks}}
  {{> adminUpdateCategory item=currentItem}}
</template>
```

**EDIT**:

When I initialize the reactive-var in the `created` callback, I set it to null, this means that until one item is clicked, the helper will return null too and when you'll try to access `this.item._id` in the `adminUpdateCategory` this will fail.

The simplest way to solve this issue is maybe to not initialize the variable to null but to the first item in the collection.

```js
Template.adminManageCategories.created=function(){
  var firstItem=Items.findOne({},{
    sort:{
      sortedField:1
    }
  });
  this.currentItemId=new ReactiveVar(firstItem && firstItem._id);
};
```

There may still be a case when you have 0 items in the collection, so you'll probably end up having to guard against the existence of the item in the JS.

```js
Template.adminUpdateCategory.helpers({
  itemProperty:function(){
    return this.item && this.item.property;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is insanely cool... Was trying it out but will wait. Thank you so much.

Comment: I though I was messing with the syntax but this should be ok.

Comment: Ok... that was too cool. I greatly appreciate your example. I was passing the values with jQuery before, but this... is way better! Thanks again.

Comment: I noticed some strange behavior when using this feature in the helper file. Everything is working, but it's throwing an error in console. 

Template.adminManageCategories.helpers({ catid: function() { return this.item._id } }); and in my adminUpdateCategory template {{catid}} works... but it's throwing the following error in the console: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at Object.Template.adminUpdateCategory.helpers.catid

Comment: Wondering if this is a bug/false positive on the error... I'm able to use the catid helper variable without problems.

Comment: Also, I can easily use item._id but just confused as to the error. Certainly not a problem, will work around it.

Comment: Tried to address this issue in my latest answer edit.