# With Meteor, how do I store a file upload's input value to be retrieved on form submit?

Tags: meteor

I have a form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name">
    <input id="picture" type="text" placeholder="/images/picture.png">
    <input type="file">
    <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

Now I'm actually using bootstrap file upload and the form is much more complex but for demo purposes I stripped it down. The file input area displays in two different ways which are conditional:

```
{{#if profile.picture}}
    Shows a version of the file upload that has the thumbnail of the picture.
    Also has a button to remove/change the picture.
{{else}}
    Shows a fresh upload because profile.picture from the data is empty.
{{/if}}
```

**Helper**

```
Template.profile.helpers({
    profile: function() {
        return Profile.findOne(id);
    }
});
```

So you can see how I'm using spacebars to determine which to show in the page.

**Events**

```
Template.profile.events({
    "change #picture-select input": function(event, template) {
        var filesList = event.currentTarget.files;
        if (filesList.length) {
            $('#picture').val("/images/" + filesList[0].name);
        } else {
            $('#picture').val("");
        }            
    }
});
```

So I can retrieve the files and send them to my methods to save the file and update the document. No problem so far.

So the problem I'm facing is, what is the proper way to do this on form submit, and not immediately when the file input changes?

**Logic:**

```
"submit form": function(event, template) {
    // ONLY perform file upload if filesList has a length ( as in the input for the file upload )
    // Also, best way to retrieve this? Like I did in the "change #picture-select input" function
});
```

I am tempted to use traditional methods via jquery to parse through the form, but I have a gut feeling I should be using some type of reactively stored true/false/filesList value somewhere that I can easily retrieve using events/rendered/callbacks/some type of method.

I tried looking at event.target on the save, but the embedded/massive amounts of arrays were overwhelming to look through.

So I guess my question is, what should I be doing on the:

```
"change #picture-select input": function(event, template) {});
```

to have the proper data stored to query against on the forms submit?

Hope this all made sense... perhaps I'm making it too complex.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you don't need a reactive variable for this.

You could simply declare a var at the top of the file and it will be global to the file only (so no worries about polluting the global namespace). Whenever the "change" event runs, set this var to the value of event.currentTarget.files, and then you can access it in the "submit" event like any normal variable.

Comment: Looks like I did over complicate things. Thank you Mark. I'm still trying to understand how all the puzzle pieces fit together.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26186384/1447679 which just happens to be another one of my questions. For whatever reason it just didn't click on how to use this in this case.

```
Template.profile.created = function() {
    var files = [];
    this.filesList = new ReactiveVar(files);
};
```

Then, in the event on the input change, I can take that file list and change the reactiveVar. Too cool.

```
"change #picture-select input": function(event, template) {
    var filesList = event.currentTarget.files;
    if (filesList.length) {
        $('#picture').val("/images/" + filesList[0].name);
        template.filesList.set(filesList);
    } else {
        $('#picture').val("");
        template.filesList.set([]);
    }
});
```

And finally, on form submit I have access to it easily:

```
"submit form": function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = event.target;
    var filesList = template.filesList.curValue;
    // so now I have it, filesList. 


},
```

Comment: fyi, I'm open to better solutions but this is working quite well.

Comment: How this will work if i have to get  event.currentTarget.files; from two or more select inputs ? I have tried to push it into an array, but it doesn't work with CollectionFs insert method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, if not just ignore it, after uploading file you want to wait with actions until form is submitted?
If so, maybe try to collect your data you want to pass in some kind of Session.